# How to write data to a file in Python (File is create but no data)

Tags: python

When I pass the file name directly as below, data is being written to the output file.

```
Rpt_file_wfl  = open('output.csv','a')

  Rpt_file_wfl.write(output)
```

But when I pass the filename as a variable, the file is getting created but there is no data.

```
OUT_PATH = E:\MYDRIVE
outDir = py_script
outFiles = output.csv
Rpt_file_wfl  = open(OUT_PATH+outDir+outFiles[0],'a')

   Rpt_file_wfl.write(output)
```

I do close the file in the end.

Why would the data not be written with the above code.

Comment: what's self? you can put code in block using 3- `-symbols at the beginning and end of a block

Comment: pls, give us all code or values of self.OUT_PATH and self.outDir and self.outFiles[0]

Comment: Out_Path = E:\Mydrive\  outDir = py_script\  outFiles = output

Comment: Are you absolutely sure what filename is being used in the second example?  I think the output is written, but to a different filename you weren't expecting.  You can add the line `print(self.OUT_PATH+self.outDir+self.outFiles[0])` to double-check the filename.

Comment: But the file is getting created.. file gets created in the same code right.

Comment: This code cannot run, there are indentation errors. And ``E:\MYDRIVE`` without quotes isn't valid syntax. Etc.

Comment: The question has two code examples, and you say one writes data to the file as expected, and the other doesn't.  Assuming `output` is the same in both cases, the only possible explanation is that the two code examples use different filenames.

Comment: I did print the file name just before the write. It does show the correct file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `os.path`

```
import os

output_text = 'some text'

drive_path = 'E:'
drive_dir = 'Mydrive'
out_dir = 'py_script'
out_file = 'output.csv'
full_path = os.path.join(drive_path, drive_dir, out_dir, out_file)


with open(full_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(output_text)
```

If it doesn't work - try to `.replace()` delimiters, like:

```
full_path = full_path.replace('/', '\\')
```

Or else:

```
full_path = full_path.replace('\\', '/')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here`s example of working code:

```
OUT_PATH='D:\\output\\'
outDir='scripts\\'
outFiles=['1.csv', '2.csv']
path = OUT_PATH+outDir+outFiles[0]
output='Example output'
with open(path, 'a') as file:
    file.write(output)
```

Comment: I tried this too already. I even use PRINT to check the file name and path before the write. It creates the file, but no data inside it.

Comment: @ViplavaVeginati this code creates file with data inside. Just run it and you`ll see.

Comment: Yes. This worked. Thank you. There was a different call down the line in a different script which was deleting my file and recreating a empty file :( .  Your code of 1. filename helped me find that out.